# How do you increase movement speed on the map in Mount & Blade

Tags: mount-and-blade

I just bought Mount & Blade off steam yesterday. On the overland map (with all the cities etc.) I see parties with speeds much higher than mine (like the 'steppe bandits' going at 7.1), is there a character attribute that's linked to this? If not, how do I increase my parties speed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are 4 ways that I remember off the top of my head, but I haven't played for a while, so I won't be much more help.

1. A hero with high pathfinding skill (remember, if you have this skill and your companion also does, you get a bonus)
2. Smaller party
3. Extra horses in your inventory
4. Amount of "infantry" and "mounted" troops, armies with more of the latter move way faster, so there are a lot of benefits of having your army composed entirely of cavalry, not even mentioning how strong it generally is.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why all those points in horse riding weren't doing anything!

Comment: Glad to be of service :)

Comment: I'm assuming "extra horses" means having some in your inventory that are not being used.  Does it matter at all what the stats are of the horses are, or will the cheapest/slowest increase overland speed as much as the fastest?

Answer (score 12):

Also, **Control + Space** speeds up in-game time on the world map, whether moving or stationary.

Don't know when this was implemented (works as of Warband 1.134), but I wish I'd had this functionality years ago.

Comment: Good to know. Map was moving way to slow for me.

Comment: I know I'm way late, but I wanted to mention that if you want to pause whilst traveling with this method, release ctrl first. But if you want to keep moving (at normal speed), release space first, as space is the pause button.