# Does having extra horses in your inventory speed up your party?

Tags: mount-and-blade, mount-and-blade-warband

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you increase movement speed on the map in Mount & Blade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5384/how-do-you-increase-movement-speed-on-the-map-in-mount-blade)

Just what the title says. Does having unused extra horses in your inventory make your party travel faster?

Answer (score 2):

*Sometimes.* Extra horses in your inventory will offset the speed loss that comes from carrying lots of heavy goods in your inventory.

However, if you aren't carrying very much in your inventory, having lots of horses could actually slow you down (since they themselves count as goods). So you have to strike a balance if you want to maximize travelling speed.

Comment: Know how this is computed? (How would I know how many horses I need, given the amount/slots of goods I have?)

Comment: Check out [this thread on the M&B forums](http://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php/topic,46362.0.html).